# SQL Error code: 4025. CONSTRAINT (trying to add a constraint for zip code check)

Tags: sql, validation, constraints, mysql-workbench

I am kinda new with databases and SQL, so I was hoping to get some help with my issue. I am trying to add a validation check for Dutch Zip codes on an existing table "order". The column I want to have checked is called "Zip" varchar(7). I used the following query which keeps giving me an error 4025:

```
ALTER TABLE `order`
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_zip
CHECK (Zip LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [a-z][a-z]');
```

I was also trying to make a trigger for the same input field, but that wasn't working either. The trigger I was trying to add:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER valid_zip
    BEFORE INSERT ON order
    FOR EACH ROW 
       BEGIN 
         IF NEW.Zip NOT LIKE '#### [a-z][a-z]' THEN 
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No valid zip'; 
         END IF; 
       END; 
 // 
DELIMITER ;
```

I am clearly doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. I want to add a validation on a input field that should match the Dutch Zip code format (0000 XX). So "1234 AA" and "2897 BC" may pass, but "44444 A" or "4444AA" can't. Thank you!

Engine: InnoDB

Programm: MySQLWorkbench 8.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to `regexp_like` as `regexp_LIKE (Zip,'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [a-z][a-z]')` in constraint instead of `Zip LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [a-z][a-z]'`.

Create table statements:

```
 create table `order` (zip varchar(7))
```

Check constraint

```
 ALTER TABLE `order`
 ADD CONSTRAINT CK_zip
 CHECK ( regexp_LIKE (Zip,'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [a-z][a-z]'));
```

insert statements:

```
 insert into `order` values('1111 aa');
 insert into `order` values('1111aa');
 insert into `order` values('1111 a');
```

Select from `order`

```
 select * from `order`
```

Output:

| zip |
| --- |
| 1111 aa |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d13d02b33d15beb84fed0d163ac959b)*

Comment: Nice. We could tighten the regex pattern a bit, though. `ALTER TABLE order ADD CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(content, '^[0-9]{4} [a-zA-Z]{2}$'))`

Comment: Best wishes for you too! And thank you for your very clear answer! However, I cannot use regexp_LIKE in MySQL somehow. I get the following error:

Error Code: 1901. Function or expression '`REGEXP_LIKE`()' cannot be used in the CHECK clause of `Ck_zip`

is there a special condition needed to use regexp_like?